# Сериализировать несколько классов в один xml файл

Tags: c#, xml, сериализация

Есть проект, в нём несколько классов. Их нужно сериализировать. Вместо отдельных файлов хочется оба класса сериализовать в один xml файл. Как это можно сделать?

Код на данный момент:
Первый класс, PRD1

```
    [Serializable]
    public class PRD1
    {
        private ObservableCollection<RList> _Provlist;
        public ObservableCollection<RList> Provlist
        {
            get { return _Provlist; }
            set { _Provlist = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(_Provlist)); }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    public class RList
    {
        public bool IsControl { get; set; }
        public string RegName { get; set; }
        public int IdRegtype { get; set; }
    }
```

Второй класс, Main_prop

```
[Serializable]
public class Main_prop
{
    public string GameDate { get; set; }
    public string Turn { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
    public Main_prop() { }
}
```

Сериализация

```
        PRD1 prd = new PRD1();
        XmlSerializer xsav = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PRD1));
        string WritePath = "result.xaml";
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(WritePath, false, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            xsav.Serialize(sw, prd);
        }
```

Comment: @AlexF элементы PRD1 и Main_prop? Извиняюсь, я немного не понимаю, а как это расписать на основе моего кода?

Comment: У вас, кстати, здесь `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(_Provlist)); }` ошибка, надо указывать не название приватного поля, а название свойства, т.е. должно быть `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Provlist)); }` или не указывать вовсе, т.к. у вас навешен атрибут `[CallerMemberName]` и компилятор подставит название свойства сам, т.е. можно написать просто `OnPropertyChanged(); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[Serializable]
class RPD_and_prop
{
    public PRD1 Rpd {get; set}
    public Main_prop Prop {get; set}
}

RPD_and_prop p = new RPD_and_prop()
{
    Rpd = new PRD1(),
    Prop = new Main_prop();
};

XmlSerializer xsav = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RPD_and_prop));
string WritePath = "result.xml";
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(WritePath, false, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
{
    xsav.Serialize(sw, p);
}
```

Comment: Сделал также - в итоге в файле оба класса пустые, т.е. ничего кроме названий Rpd и Prop нету. Хотя коллекция в PRD1 заполнена элементами. Тоже самое и с Main_prop, только там все переменные видны, но со значением null.